# How to use ActivityIndicator between code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a very short and simple question to you. I don't understand why. Because I'm new to React Native. I am sorry for this. My English level is not very good.

*That's how it works*

```
{ isLoadingCustomer ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 13 }}> Loading.. </Text> : totalCustomer }
```

*But it doesn't work that way*

```
{ isLoadingCustomer ? <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="white" /> : totalCustomer }
```

That's weird. Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance.

```
    <View style={styles.dashboard}>                    
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
            <View style={styles.activies}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 15, color: 'white', marginTop: -17 }}> Günlük Aktivitelerim </Text>

                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: -25 }}>
                    <View style={styles.activitiesResult}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, color: 'green' }}> Olumlu </Text>
                        { isLoadingPositive ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 40 }}> Yükleniyor.. </Text> : <Text style={styles.textResult}> { totalPositive } </Text> }
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.activitiesResult}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, color: 'red' }}> Olumsuz </Text>                                    
                        { isLoadingPostponed ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 40 }}> Yükleniyor.. </Text> : <Text style={styles.textResult}> { totalNegative } </Text> }
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.activitiesResult}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, color: 'blue' }}> Satış </Text>                                    
                        { isLoadingSale ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 40 }}> Yükleniyor.. </Text> : <Text style={styles.textResult}> { totalSale } </Text> }
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.activitiesResult}>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 12, color: 'black' }}> Ertelenme </Text>                                    
                        { isLoadingNegative ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 40 }}> Yükleniyor.. </Text> : <Text style={styles.textResult}> { totalPostponed } </Text> }
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>                       
        </View>

        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', marginTop: 20 }}>
            <TouchableHighlight activeOpacity={0.4} underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Lead')}>
                <View style={styles.leads}>
                    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 13, color: 'white', marginTop: 3 }}> Müşteri Adaylarım </Text>

                    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', lineHeight: 45 }}>                                     
                        { isLoadingLead ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 13 }}> Yükleniyor.. </Text> : totalLead }
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>

            <View style={styles.customers}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 13, color: 'white', marginTop: 3 }}> Müşterilerim </Text>

                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', lineHeight: 45 }}> 
                    { isLoadingCustomer ? <Text style={{ fontSize: 13 }}> Yükleniyor.. </Text> : totalCustomer }
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

Comment: both code snippets should be functional, what are are u getting??

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unexpected context found on stack. This error is likely caused by a bug in React. Please file an issue

Comment: Are you sure, the props `color`  gets string? try with hex value

Comment: There is no problem if I use this way in the top line. I get the same error when I remove all attributes. That's weird. @Amir-Mousavi

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@aeid/cmVzdG

Comment: @Dodiş please share the context where you render this line of code ... your whole render method if possible

Comment: That might be some error in what you return, send in the whole `View` snippet

Comment: I shared the entire line of code with you. @Amir-Mousavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `Text` component does not accept an `ActivityIndicator` as a children ... but your `Text` component could have a nested Text component inside of it

That's why this line is not working:

```
<Text>{ isLoadingCustomer ? <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="white" /> : totalCustomer }</Text>
```

This would work:

```
  <View>
      {isLoadingCustomer ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="white" />
      ) : (
        <Text>{totalCustomer}</Text>
      )}
    </View>
```

Comment: Isn't that ridiculous? How do I put loading?

Comment: you could render your `ActivityIndicator` **Directly** inside a `View` component ... and it would work

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example

```
    </View>
       <View>
             <Text style={Styles.flatListItemText}>Your text here </Text> 
      </View>

    {(this.state.showLoading) ?
                    <ActivityIndicator
                           size="small"
                           color="white" /> : null }
     </View>
```

Change show loading status using this

```
 /**
 * 
 * @param {bol} status 
 */
showLoading(status) {
    this.setState({ showLoading: status })
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy problem solved. I saw what the error was.